# How to count the number of unique absolute values in an array with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

There is a given array that is not empty and it consists of N values. The array is sorted in ascending order.

The task is to write a function that counts the number of unique absolute values ​​in the array.

For example, the array A is:

A [0] = -5

A [1] = -3

A [2] = -1

A [3] = 0

A [4] = 3

A [5] = 6

The absolute number is a unique 5 because there are 5 unique absolute values ​​that are 0,1,3,5,6.

Suppose that:

N is the integer range [1 .. 100,000]; array a is sorted in ascending order.

So far I've done this:

```
class AbsoluteUnique

  def initialize int_array
    puts "Enter content for the array:"
    5.times do
      int_array << gets

      if A.size == 5
        find_count
      end
    end
  end

  def find_count

  end
end
```

Obviously that isn't enough, but I find it difficult to figure out the rest of the function. Could you please help me find those 5 absolute, unique values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an integer array `a` like so:

```
a = [-5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6]
```

This should do it:

```
a.map {|n| n.abs}.uniq.length
```

If it needs to be take an array for standard input, this would be the way to do that:

```
a = []
puts "Enter 5 integers separated by newlines: "
until(a.length == 5)
  a << gets.chomp.to_i
end
puts "There are #{a.map {|n| n.abs}.uniq.length} unique absolute values in your list."
```

Answer (score 6):

Uniq takes an optional block - the result of the block is compared for uniqueness instead of the value itself - so you can do

```
array.uniq(&:abs).length
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
array.map(&:abs).uniq.count
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[-5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6].group_by(&:abs).length
# => 5
```